# Moment.js subtract variable not working

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a piece of code like this:

```
var exadate = "2016-03-06 02:15:54";                //Some date
var time = "5 days"                                 //Need to subtract this
var reldate = time.split(" ");                      //Make 2 subtract variables

var timestamp = moment(exadate,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").subtract(reldate[0],reldate[1]).format("D MMM YYYY|HH:mm");
```

It returns "**6 Mar 2016|02:15**" instead of "**1 Mar 2016|02:15**".

However if I specify the `.subtract()` as `.subtract(reldate[0],"days")`, it does subtract it correctly. But the `time` I'll be subtracting ranges from minutes to days so the string has to be a variable.

Even more puzzling is that this exact line worked perfectly before I updated my code. The changes however should have no effect of this part of the code.

Comment: You have an extra period:  `moment.(exadate` should be `moment(exadate`.  It errors with it in, and returns the correct value with removed.

Comment: Oh yes, this is actually a mistake I made when making this post. I corrected it.
In the actual script I'm using the moment-timezone.js as well and this period was part of `moment.tz(exadate,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss","Europe/London")`. I could give the whole thing but this isn't the issue. I've tested with and without moment-timezone and the only time it worked was if i specified the string directly, not as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work:

```js
var exadate = "2016-03-06 02:15:54";                //Some date
var time = "5 days"                                 //Need to subtract this
var reldate = time.split(" ");                      //Make 2 subtract variables

var timestamp = moment(exadate,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").subtract(reldate[0],reldate[1]).format("D MMM YYYY|HH:mm");

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = timestamp;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an version of moment.js of 2.6.0 or older.   Version 2.7.0 introduced (in [#1704](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/1704)) the ability to support strings as input and place the number before the units with the `add` and `subtract` functions.

It would probably work if you did this instead:

```
.subtract(reldate[1], +reldate[0])
```

Notice the order switched, and the `+` to coerce to number.

However the better idea is just to update to the current release, which is 2.12.0 as of this post.  Your code will work without any modification, and many other enhancements, new features, and bug fixes will be yours for free.